# Sandbox Theme Center Menu Elements

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The theme is here (the page is a live preview) http://www.plaintxt.org/themes/sandbox/

I've been trying with all mixtures of text-align: center; and margin: 0 auto;
I just can't seem to move the elements of the menu into the center of the page.

Any help would be great :)

Comment: In future you can ask these kind of questions here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, right now its private beta...

Answer (score 0):

use a `width:XXXpx` (for example 800px) for `div#menu ul` and also set a `margin:0 auto;` to this. You have to set a width to center elements with `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: Thanks but:
I was basing my CSS off: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal16.htm

It doesn't have a width: XXXpx though?

Comment: the link you provided, doesn't use submenus. maybe the problem found in your submenus declarations